# What are the benefits of using Nessus in addition to Azure Security Center?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, azure, nessus

Are there any benefits to using vulnerability scanners such as Nessus Pro or Tenable.io, if we are already using Azure Security Center for vulnerability and update management?

Or does it have any negative effects to do so?

Comment: I edited the title and body of your question to be more readable and consistent. If this is against your intentions, please roll back to your original version

Comment: Looks that you need to compare both products and decide whats best for you, probably they will have different features for sure.

Comment: It looks like they even state in their manual that you can in addition to checking for insecure configurations add a vulnerability assessment tool https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-vulnerability-assessment-recommendations

Answer (score 2):

Azure Security Center rather identifies insecure configurations (e.g. missing system updates) than concrete vulnerabilities. While Nessus authenticated scans also cover insecure configurations, they additionally discovers vulnerable installed software (e.g. through CVE matching).

I dont think that the Azure Security Center sees itself as vulnerability assessment solution. Nessus definitely does that. I would say if you have moderate to high security requirements you should use both.